# Undo stemming after tm::stemDocument()?

Tags: r, tm, stemming

I have a list of stemmed words in R. Now, I want to undo my stemming in order to receive a list of all the "complete" words in R.

This is the code I used for stemming my wordlist:

```
library(tm)

Stemmed.words <- tm_map(Stemmed.words, stemDocument, language = "english")
```

But is there a function to reverse the stemming?

Comment: Consider adding a bit more information to your post. E.g. what libraries you are using, what data you have, what result you are expecting etc.

Comment: I have no idea what `Stemmed.words` is either on input or output from that expression, but the obvious way to do what you want is to keep the original words.  Don't try to reverse the operation, just keep both "before" and "after" versions of the word list.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to reverse the stemming using the `tm` package. It provides a fumction `stemCompletion`, which provides different options to find the original word based on the word-stem.
This is very helpful for everyone doing a textual analysis.